# It Is A Tradition

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Some question about these two sentences:

1. "It is a tradition ***for*** a son to inherit the family business."
2. "It is a tradition ***that*** a son inherits the family business."

I have a feeling that the second sentence is not as good as the first.  What do native speakers think?

Comment: Both are completely fine, although the second may sound a bit stilted/formal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of the sentences you've given, the second sounds better to me; in my experience, using the noun *tradition* calls for a dependent clause with *that* to explain the nature of the tradition, while the adjective *traditional* generally takes the prepositional *for*-clause.

I'd probably prefer the adjective/for-clause formation as the most natural form, though:

> It's traditional for a son to inherit the family business.

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=traditional+for,traditional+that,tradition+for,tradition+that&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,traditional%20for;,c0;.t1;,traditional%20that;,c0;.t4;,tradition%20for;,c0;,s0;;tradition%20for;,c0;;Tradition%20for;,c0;.t1;,tradition%20that;,c0) seem to support your assertions.

Comment: Or _"Traditionally, a son will inherit the family business."_ I think I like the adverbial form even better.

Answer (score 1):

I think *for* sounds better than *that*, but I wouldn't cringe if an writer used *that* instead of *for*.

One other thing worth noting, though, is that the article before *tradition* is unnecessary:

> It's tradition for a son to inherit the family business.

Anyhow, there are many ways to improve what you have written; the *for*/*that* dilemma is not the area where the sentence could be improved. Get rid of the passive voice:

> By tradition, a son inherits the family business.

Comment: er... what passive voice?

Comment: @Aant - that's not the first time I've misdiagnosed the "passive voice", and it probably won't be the last. But I still think: "By tradition, a son inherits the family business" sounds more direct than: "It is a tradition for a son to inherit the family business."

Comment: yep, I certainly agree that your version is more idiomatic, just not that the other is in the passive voice, which has a precise technical meaning (and would refer to something like the somewhat ridiculous “By tradition, family businesses are inherited by sons”).